# How can I refer other objects in php?

Tags: java, php

I'm very new to Php and I'm from Java. I have a class in Java like this:

```
class A {
}

class B{
}
```

in same package. Inside class `A` I have defined a datatype of type `B` like :

```
   B bType;
```

I want the same behavior in php. Is that possible to do so?

And are there any way to "package" my classes in php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ref: http://in2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: PHP does not have static typing, you cannot declare the type of a property. However, you can use a [type hint](http://php.net/oop5.typehinting) to ensure that the type of an object passed to a *method* is correct, so if you use setter/getters this limitation can be overcome. Having said that, you should examine whether you need to do this anyway - if the two classes are tightly coupled, especially if `B` is instantiated within `A`, you likely don't need this because `A`s implementation will be rigid. But the promiscuity of OOP in PHP coming from Java will take some getting used to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `A` class define:

```
$BClass = new B(arguments for contructor);
$BClass = new B; //without contructor
```

Comment: You even don't need to curly braces when initiating a class providing it doesn't take any arguments. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespaces (which is *packaging*). If you really want to *package* then you should take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php (but I guess til' now, nobody really does that).

You can force types in functions but not for variables.

```
function (Array $bla, YourClass $test) {
   /** ... **/
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support static typing but you can use type hinting to define a data-type within a method. For example...

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function test(B $b) // Must be a method within B or a new exception will be thrown.
    {
        echo 1 + $b->test(); // adds one plus the return value of $b->test() from the B class.
    }
}

class B
{
    public function test() 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

    class C
    {
         public function test()
         {
              $b = new B; // initializes the B class.
              return $b->test(); // calls the test method within the B class.
         }
    }

$a = new A;
$a->test(new B); // returns 2
```

You could also use `gettype($a)` to detect a certain data-type.